# Postgresql 9.1 -> 9.4 migration problems

Tags: postgresql

I've run a quick and dirty debian 7 -> debian 8 upgrade today, and lost my postgresql 9.1 installation. By "lost" i mean that i can't start it from init script (i simply get no output; 9.4 goes okay, though) and `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres` binary seems missing, so i couldn't migrate from 9.1 to 9.4 using `pg_update`. I'm okay with all possible solutions (bringing 9.1 back or migrating to 9.4), but i don't know where to start. Aptitude shows "postgresql-9.1" package as "c" - is it safe to just install over? If yes, which directory should i back up first?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone *quick and dirty* way again, and everything booted up just fine with old data present:

- I've zipped `/etc/postgresql/9.1` folder to backup configuration setting
- Then i've found the directory data is stored in (`cat /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf | grep data_directory`) and zipped is as well (and i've required sudo to gain access to some files)
- After all of that i just used aptitude to install `postgresql-9.1` package, which has put up corresponding service right after installation

There was no need in backups in my case, but if anyone finds himself on this page with a similar problem - i **strongly** recommend doing them.